# Fixing syntax highlighting without needed to add language tags to every answer

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I answered a question, and noticed that the syntax highlighting was off. It was a Clojure question, but Java was being favored. I have a couple comments in the code that read poorly under Java highlighting, so I'd like to fix the highlighting.

Is there any way to fix highlighting after the fact if it infers incorrectly, besides adding explicit `<!-- language-all: lang-* -->` tags? The problem with just using the tag is it only effects the question it's in (from my experience). Anyone who adds an answer will need to add the tag too to get good highlighting.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48367066/3000206)

Comment: I missed the "default" part, although that doesn't really explain how it can be fixed besides tagging every post if it infers incorrectly.

Comment: Could you post the link to the question? I'm assuming the question is tagged with [java] and [clojure]?

Comment: @SensibleAlexander Whoops, I had a link. It got edited out. Sec.

Comment: This should probably be discussed on [Stack Overflow's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). The original question was tagged with both Java and Clojure. Only questions have tags so when a question has multiple tags you may need to indicate the language of the answer manually.